# Xcode 5.11 crashes on opening a project

Tags: xcode5

Hi While opening a specific project Xcode 5.11 on OS X 10.9.4. also while trying to export accounts i get could not export identity from keychain

error while opening is

```
Process:         Xcode [4305]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [493]
Responsible:     Xcode [4305]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-19 08:00:57.254 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  3E0DC55B-B018-5F35-E64F-7B2D712CA26C


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): -[NSFileWrapper fileWrappers] *** this method is only for directory type NSFileWrappers
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been there before. Try deleting a file called xcuserdata, it's part of your project:

- open a Finder window and navigate to your project
- right-click on the .xcproject file
- select "show Package contents"
- a new Finder window opens
- delete the .xcuserdata file and close the Finder window

Now open your project again and - hopefully - Xcode should no longer crash.

http://pinkstone.co.uk/xcode-crashes-every-time-you-open-it-and-how-to-fix-it/